# ATTLIST name different than ELEMENT name

Tags: xml, dtd

I have this code:

```
<!ENTITY % id "id ID #IMPLIED">
<!ENTITY % comment "comment CDATA #REQUIRED">

...

<!ELEMENT methodology (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST methodology %id;>

<!ELEMENT updated (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST info %comment;>
```

Why for the comment the name of the info ATTLIST is different of his ELEMENT name?
And I don't know if in XML I have this code for element updated:

```
<updated comment="This is a comment">
DATE
</updated>
```

Comment: Can you post the full DTD? Or at least all the parts that refer to the elements you are talking about (elements `info`, `updated`, and ATTLISTs that use `%comment;`, `info` and `updated`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your DTD, you `<updated>` may not have a `comment` attribute (unless it's declared in the parts that you omitted.)

The `info` `ATTLIST` is the list of attributes for the `<info>` element. The syntax for `ATTLIST` is:

```
<!ATTLIST element-name attribute-name attribute-type default-declaration>
```

The declaration for the `<info>` element in your DTD is:

```
<!ATTLIST info comment CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

`%comment;` is a reference to the parameter entity which was declared in the beginning of the file Parameter entities are useful if you need to reuse bits of code many times. Your `%comment;` entity defines a string which is a part of the `ATTLIST` declaration. Perhaps the `%comment;` parameter entity is used a lot in your code because all or many elements have a `comment` attribute, so you could avoid retyping it many times using the entity. If `updated` has a `comment` attribute it might be defined as:

```
<!ATTLIST updated %comment;>
```

*But* it would be perfectly valid to *not* use the entity as well:

```
<!ATTLIST updated comment CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

Your `%id;` entity has the same purpose. The attribute list for `<methodology>` could also have been declared without the entity as:

```
<!ATTLIST methodology id ID #IMPLIED>
```

You can read more about parameter entities. They aren't hard to understand. Check this tutorial: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tiparam/